# fuse: warning: library too old, some operations may not not work

Tags: centos, fuse, s3fs

I'm trying to mount my s3 bucket to my server.(Centos 6) and when a run the following command

```
s3fs -o use_cache=/tmp/cache localdir bucket-name
```

I'm getting an error

```
fuse: warning: library too old, some operations may not not work
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of fuse are you using?

Try to install manually 2.8.4, see instructions:
https://kisdigital.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/installing-s3fs-on-rhelcentos/